# VS code uses its wrong env of GOROOT

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code as my editor for Golang projects, a couple of days ago it started highlighting package definitions as syntax errors, saying "Cannot find GOROOT". Either I cannot run or compile my Golang programs via VS Code terminal, but it works fine in Ubuntu terminal. Exporting GOROOT="" in VS Code terminal allows me to run and compile programs, but incorrect syntax highlighting still remains. I already tried removing VS Code completely and installing it again. Any ideas what might cause the problem?

Comment: Check if you have set it up properly https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH

Comment: use Go Jetbrains